# Gmail ckeckbox and button

Tags: html, button, checkbox, gmail

Is it possible to add a checkbox and a button that only enables when all the checkboxes are checked in a gmail?

I already have this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" value="condiciones"> Acepto los terminos y condiciones<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="politica" value="privacidad" checked> Acepto la política de privacidad<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sorteo" value="Car" checked> Acepto las condiciones del sorteo<br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But I do not have the button as I do not know how to do it.

Can you help me?

(Moreover, I would like to have a big centered red button with white letters, but for now I only want to know how to make the button. If you can solve this too I would be so grateful)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you will need to use JavaScript to show/hide the button depending on if all buttons are checked or not. Here's an example of how that might look:

```
function checkAllClicked() {
    let button = document.getElementById('button');
    if(document.getElementById('box1').checked &&
        document.getElementById('box2').checked &&
        document.getElementById('box3').checked) {
      button.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      button.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

This function basically checks whether all buttons (with IDs `box1`, `box2` and `box3`) are checked using the logic behind a [logical AND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate), and toggles whether the button is visible or not.

Here it is in the context of your webpage:

```js
function checkAllClicked() {
  const button = document.getElementById('button');
  // check if check boxes are all selected
  if(document.getElementById('box1').checked &&
      document.getElementById('box2').checked &&
      document.getElementById('box3').checked) {
    // display the submit button
    button.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // hide the submit button
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="terminos" value="condiciones" onclick="checkAllClicked()"> Acepto los terminos y condiciones<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="politica" value="privacidad" checked  onclick="checkAllClicked()"> Acepto la política de privacidad<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box3" name="sorteo" value="Car" checked  onclick="checkAllClicked()"> Acepto las condiciones del sorteo<br>
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" style="display: none;">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously `/action_page.php` will have to exist for the form to do anything, otherwise the code will look for a `.php` file which doesn't exist and throw an error.

Comment: Thank you James for taking your time to answer my question. I think I understood everything.

Answer (score 0):

No.

I'm not aware of any email client that supports JavaScript (or any other kind of program logic) embedded in an HTML formatted email.

GMail's web UI certainly doesn't support that.

Comment: So the only way that I see here is to find a website that let's me include javascript. Are you aware of any website that lets me do a checkbox and a button, something like google forms but only for this prupose?

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that actually... if you want people to confirm everything in an email, you could probably only do one of two things: combine all checks into a simple hyperlink rather than selection boxes, or have a link in your email which takes you to a web page containing this disappearing/appearing submit button.